# Find in Eclipse all classes that are under specific package

Tags: eclipse

I have project in which I have a package "com.mysite.Entities". Under this package I have several entities: "Class1.java","Class2.java","Class3.java". Currently in the names we don't have the string "Entity". And now I want to find what entities I have in this package. I want to write somewhere the package and as a result to have the 3 classes defined above.
Is this possible in Eclipse?
I don't want to find them with java code. What I need is just in some way to search in Eclipse IDE and to see in the UI that there are 3 classes, which were written under this package and to be able to select one of them and to open it into the Editor Window.

Comment: What do you mean by "find them"? Find them with/for what? If you want to find them using Java code, take a look into Java Reflections.

Comment: In _Search > Java..._, enter the search string `com.mysite.Entities.*`, search for _Type_ and limit to _Declarations_. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes this is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ***Search > Java...***, enter the search string **`com.mysite.Entities.*`**, search for ***Type*** and limit to ***Declarations***.